# Passing x509 certificates into node express server, NOT over https

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, x509

I have searched and searched but everything I seem to find on this topic is regarding setting up a node express server to use HTTPS, and this is NOT what I am trying to achieve.

I would like to know, regardless of using HTTPS or not, is it safe (and more importantly good practice) to pass in client x.509 certificates into a post request, and then parse and use the client certificate.

If I could provide an example that may help.

I have a simple medical application where users authenticate to a node express route using username and password, also, I already have HTTPS configured and working.

However, later in the stages of using the client application, I need the user to be able to pass in their x.509 certificate, and allow data to be verified with their public key.

Now, I understand that authentication is carried out at the initial connection for https, but this is different, so I was thinking I could pass the users certificate as a json object and create/use the certificate in the express route.

At first thought this should be fine as the certificate is public, and we have already established a secure endpoint, however, I am very surprised that I am not able to find any examples or tutorials on this, so perhaps for some reason I am not aware, this is not best practice?

Any advice or guidance would be great.

Thanks in advance.
Regards
Steve

Answer (score 0):

If you do not do mTLS (via HTTPS) you will need to develop a protocol to authenticate the user who presents the certificate is in-fact the private key holder. This is not trivial to get right, not doing this means you will be exposed to trivial spoofing attacks.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am actually using HTTPS, however, I then need to use client certificates further down the line. Is it OK to pass these in to my REST API end point and use the certificate to decrypt a challenge with the cert public key, for example? Thanks. Stephen

Comment: The user presenting a certificate will tell you nothing. Remember a certificate is public, anyone can have a copy of the certificate. To prove you are the user reflected in the certificate you must perform an operation with the corresponding private key. That is what happens with MTLS.

Comment: Yes I understand that. Is it ok to request a challenge via the rest api in my node app, then the user encrypts this with his public key and posts this plus the certificate to a different end point in my node is server. Then I can verify. Like I said I use initial TLS HTTPs on the server but need functionality where I will use certificates further to that. Thanks

Comment: Just to add to the above. Some users will need a certificate and Smartcard but some users will be using password so that’s why I also wanted to handle cert authentication in a different way. Also the certificates will be used for other purposes. Eg signing data and sending that to the server so again, would need to send the certificate so server can verify signature. Root ca cert would be on the node server also

Comment: While one can design a authentication protocol that uses certificates designing a secure variant is harder than it seems on the surface. The “verification of the root certificate” is the smallest possible part of that. I do not believe it is possible to design a secure protocol via stack overflow posts

Comment: Thanks. No that's fine I do not expect to do this, I am simply trying to figure out if this is a common and acceptable way. The initial authentication is handled via mTLS, however, I need my users to sign data and send it to my rest api, so they would need to also send their certificate so I can verify, and that would mean checking they have the private key. so I thought of doing it this way and sending back a challenge response so they can encrypt with the private key. When I run searches I am only finding tutorials and info on mTLS, but I already have that up and running. Thanks again

Comment: For signing data you can use webcrypto and browser bound certificates. Here is a post I did on this: http://unmitigatedrisk.com/?p=503 you can use one of my libraries, PKI.js, to do this

Comment: Thanks but this would be from a desktop based electron app which need to communicate with my node is rest api. Hence the original question, however, would this still be the best solution? Regards. Stephen

Comment: Sorry, not possible to explain to someone how to build a secure authentication protocol  over stack overflow posts. Good luck.